# SQL to find distinct multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that holds information for rooms, it contains amongst others a column for BLDGCODE and another for COSTCODE. Each room in the building (BLDGCODE) can only be assigned a single costcode and these can be all be the same value or different values.

Am trying to write a script that only shows buildings with more than one distinct cost code assigned to its many rooms, for example several rooms could have cost code ABC and others 999 which is what I want to identify and report on. I have tried with the below thinking a CTE would get me the results, however I am still seeing buildings with only the one cost code that are repeated for multiple rooms in the building.

```
with CTE
as (
    select rtrim(fmb0.reg_code) as Region,
        rtrim(Country) as Country,
        rtrim(fmb0.BLDGCODE) as BLDGCODE,
        (
            case 
                when FMB0.BLDGSTATUS = 'CAD'
                    then 'Yes'
                else 'No'
                end
            ) as CAD,
        group_ as GROUP_,
        fma0.usable,
        fmb0.nia,
        fmb0.niahprev
    from fmb0
    left join fma0 on fmb0.bldgcode = fma0.bldgcode
    left join fmey on fmb0.propsubtyp = fmey.ey_key
    left join fme2 on fmb0.country = fme2.descrip
    where fme2.is_live = 1
        and fmey.bau = 1
        and fmb0.bldgcode not like 'xx%'
        and fma0.bldgcode like 'cn%'
    )
select CTE.Region,
    CTE.Country,
    CTE.BLDGCODE,
    CTE.GROUP_,
    sum(cte.usable) as AREA,
    cte.nia,
    cte.niahprev,
    CTE.CAD
from CTE
where CTE.CAD = 'No'
group by CTE.BLDGCODE,
    cte.group_,
    cte.country,
    cte.region,
    cte.nia,
    cte.cad,
    cte.niahprev
having count(CTE.GROUP_) > 1
order by 1, 2, 3
```

How do I remove those buildings that despite having multiple occurances the cost code is the same, and only show those that have more than one cost code within which are different?

So here is the code referencing a single table:

```
with CTE as (
select 
rtrim(fma0.BLDGCODE) as BLDGCODE, 
group_ as GROUP_,
fma0.usable
from fma0
where 
fma0.bldgcode like 'cn%'
)
select 
CTE.BLDGCODE,
CTE.GROUP_ AS COSTCODE,
sum(cte.usable) as AREA
from CTE
group by CTE.BLDGCODE, cte.group_
having count(CTE.GROUP_) > 1
order by 1
```

Example data set would be:

```
RMID      BLDGCODE    COSTCODE    AREA
01.01     01          AA-01       10
01.02     01          AS-05       20
01.03     01          XY-99       30
01.04     01          XY-99       70
02.01     02          AA-01       10
02.02     02          AA-01       20
02.03     02          AA-01       20
```

Expected results would be:

```
BLDGCODE     COSTCODE     AREA
01           AA-01        10
01           AS-05        20
01           XY-99        100
```

BLDGCODE 02 would not be shown as it only has a single cost code

Thanks

Comment: Your statement about "a table" seems to have nothing to do with your query that involves many tables.  Sample data and desired results would help clarify.

Comment: Try `HAVING MIN(costcode) <> MAX(costcode)` (at least two different cost codes), which is more efficient than `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT costcode) > 1`

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, but both examples return zero values

Comment: Try with `count(DISTINCT CTE.GROUP_) > 1`

Comment: Thanks Josh, zero results again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all those rows with multiple costcodes, so a simple aggregation doesn't work. You can to do the same logic using another cte with Windowed Aggregates instead:

```
with CTE as (
select 
   rtrim(fma0.BLDGCODE) as BLDGCODE, 
   group_ as GROUP_,
   fma0.usable
from fma0
where fma0.bldgcode like 'cn%'
)
,counts as
 (
   select 
      CTE.BLDGCODE,
      CTE.GROUP_ AS COSTCODE,
      sum(cte.usable) as AREA,
      case when min(CTE.GROUP_) over (partition by CTE.BLDGCODE) 
             <> max(CTE.GROUP_) over (partition by CTE.BLDGCODE)
           then 1
           else 0
      end as flag
   from CTE
   group by CTE.BLDGCODE, cte.group_
 ) 
select *
from counts
where flag = 1
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth but I can't seem to get that to work, would you mind including my simplified SQL above and embedd in your answer?

Comment: @FredTheDog: Edited my answer, this should work now.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I need to understand better how to nest CTE statements.